# Visual Studio compilation error UWP

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, asynchronous, uwp

I am building a UWP app on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. I am encountering errors where Compiler says "async is not a feature of C# 4.0 use 5.0 or greater", "Windows namespace cannot be found"

Error   CS8025  Feature 'async function' is not available in C# 4.
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ConnectionProfile'

However upon closing my solution and reopening it these errors disappear. And my app runs(in debug mode). However after a few debug sessions the problem resurfaces.

To Correct any errors on my part I Have :

1> Reset VS user Settings

2>Reinstalled VS

3>Reset Windows 10

But the problem doesn't want to go. I am using Windows 10 Home Edition and also I don't use insider builds. Recreated my project from scratch

As a result even the most basic tasks performed in my code appear erroneous.

Comment: when you created a new project.. which version of .NET Framework did you target? Can you paste  a screen shot of your New Project Template with version # ?

Comment: .NET 4.5.2 It was selected by default.And I didn't alter anything there I am sure

Comment: Before I recommend you to download and install the latest .net framework manually ... Try to create a simple console app and get it building using the template and if it works we can isolate the issue to UWP tools.

Comment: setting UWP target framework to minimum 4.6 solves the problem though why it shouldn't work for 4.5.2 is an open question

Comment: I'm a bit confused here as UWP isn't .net framework version based - its OS based.

Answer (score 0):

Can you revise if you have installed **[Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/)** as a nuget package? Wen you create a new uwp project, automatically its added.

I had similar problem that some namespaces was not encountered and the answer was this nuget package.

[image]